# Is that possible to print NSLocale currency in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency, nslocale

Iam looking for a code that can display the NSLocale currency format.

I used below codes

```
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [formatter setLocale:skProduct.priceLocale];
        NSLog(@"formatter%@",formatter);

        NSLog(@"%@",skProduct.priceLocale);  ////  i want to print NSLocale value

      NSString*  currencyString = [formatter stringFromNumber:skProduct.price];
  NSLog(@"currencyString price %@",currencyString);
```

How can i display exact price amount depend on NSLocale ,When i tried NSLog(@"%@",skProduct.priceLocale);  It displaying like some memory locations..
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
  [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
  NSString*  currencyString = [formatter currencySymbol];
  NSLog(@"currencyString %@",currencyString);
```

Comment: no boss,am looking to convert the price amount not the currency symbol or code , i want INR 59.8  to $ 1  conversion

Comment: if i print like "skProduct.price"  then it will print in INR format(Indian rupee)  instead of current locale country

Comment: @Navi, in this case, you need get currency rate and convert it manual, I think.

Comment: i have developed that code but i need to know anythng from apple side is possible ?

Comment: @Navi no, NSLocale doesn't have this function, see documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html